# Google Play Services sign-in not working after opening an URL in android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, google-play-games

I've added Google Play Game Services support in my app, implementing `GameHelperListener`. Sign-in and sign-out workflow worked fine.

But every time I open a URL, either from my application or outside, I can not perform the sign-in. The program hangs with the message:

```
!!! GameHelper WARNING: beginUserInitiatedSignIn() called when already connecting-...
```

and  callbacks (`onSignInSucceeded` and `onSignInFailed`) are not called.

```
!!! GameHelper WARNING: beginUserInitiatedSignIn() called when already connecting. Be patient! You can only call this method after you get an onSignInSucceeded() or onSignInFailed() callback. Suggestion: disable the sign-in button on startup and also when it's clicked, and re-enable when you get the callback.
```

How is possible that opening a URL can affect this process?

Code I'm using to login include:

```
@Override
public void loginGPGS() {
try {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn(getApplicationContext());
            }
        });
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

and

```
gameHelper.setup(this);
```

and

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    gameHelper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could be that play services is signing you out externally, though I do not know why that would happen - unless the user requests it.

Give this a try - it is used when the user manually signs-out "outside" your app:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
   if ( request == REQUEST_CODE && response == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED )  {
      gameHelper.disconnect();
   }
   else  {
      gameHelper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
   }
}
```

**NOTE:** The `REQUEST_CODE` should match the request code you used.

Not sure if this will work in your case - and you might want to `reconnect()` instead of `disconnect`. This is just an example.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure you are overriding `onStart()` like this:

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    gameHelper.onStart(this);
}
```